# Select record with highes column value in group by

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I do a group by on a version field.

The thing is I want to select the record with the highest version number (aka most recent record).

This is what my database looks like:

productinformation:

[image: producinformation table]

productinformation_content:

[image]

This is what my query looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM productinformation
LEFT JOIN productinformation_content
    ON productinformation_content_sourceid = productinformation_id
WHERE productinformation_content_lang = 'en' AND
      productinformation_content_active = 1
GROUP BY productinformation_content_sourceid
ORDER BY productinformation_content_title ASC
```

There can be multimple records with the same productinformation_content_sourceid so I grouped on that field but I need the record with the highest productinformation_content_version of that group

Can anyone help me out?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have date create and update. Why don't you use these columns to order by?

Comment: I'm afraid that your question, as it stands now, will likely not be helpful to anyone else, and may not even be answerable.  Please _edit_ your question and show sample data for the two tables along with the expected output.

Comment: Could you order by the version too? `ORDER BY productinformation_content_version DESC, productinformation_content_title ASC`

Comment: @JimWright I tried that, unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: What output do you get? Trying swapping the columns around in the `ORDER BY` statement. I've edited my previous comment.

Comment: @JimWright I've tried that also and still doesn't work :) I get same results maybe it has to do something with the left join?

Comment: I don't know how why this is marked as duplicate I tried the solutions in the marked question but nothing works.

Comment: Your question does not indicate in any way that you are aware of the duplicate question and how you tried to implement any of the solutions offered there. This is why your question is a duplicate: you asked the same question with different data.